# Why isn't my navbar toggling with bootstrap?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I looked over my code a few million times, comparing it to the example on the official docs page. Spell checked. Watched a tutorial. I also checked that I added the right JS files. Why isn't my nav links toggling?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Hello, world!</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
        <link href="src/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link
            href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        />
    </head>
    <body>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
                <!-- Nav logo -->
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
                    <img
                        src="https://www.designfreelogoonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/000707-online-digital-eye-logo-free-logo-maker-02.png"
                        alt="logo image"
                        style="width: 100px;"
                    />
                    <span>TechStyle</span>
                </a>
                
                <!-- Nav button toggler -->
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type= "button" data-toggle="collapase" data-target="#navLinks" aria-controls="navLinks" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
                </button>

                <!-- nav links -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"  id="navLinks">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Apply</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to your problem, you can use the code I modified.

Edits:

1. I matched the *button-toggler* data-bs-toggle with the collapse id.
2. I replaced all the scripts to the current bundle `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Hello, world!</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
        <link href="src/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link
            href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        />
    </head>
    <body>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
                <!-- Nav logo -->
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
                    <img
                        src="https://www.designfreelogoonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/000707-online-digital-eye-logo-free-logo-maker-02.png"
                        alt="logo image"
                        style="width: 100px;"
                    />
                    <span>TechStyle</span>
                </a>
                
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                  
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
            </nav>

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your imported CSS is for Bootstrap **v5.0.2**, whereas your JS imports are for **v4.4.1** which are not compatible. The older version also required the `popper` and `jquery`. You are however, using the syntax for the older Bootstrap, so your options would be to either add the CSS for the older version, or replace the syntax and the JS files with the newer version.

For option #1, replace your CSS import with this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">`

For option #2,
remove all the 3 script imports from the bottom, and replace with this:

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

If you do this (#2), you'd also need to change all `data-*` attributes with `data-bs-*` attributes. I'd advice to refer to the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/navbar).

Comment: I didn't know I was usung an old version, thanks for ketting me know! I tried both of the options and none of them fixed my problem somehow, after multiple refreshes, checking that i pasted the new css link, and for option two replacing the js files and adding -bs in the data attributes,  and trying the code in a chrome browser. Any ideas?

Comment: It was a misspelling that made it not work after changing the links and things, thanks for your help!